# Converting exceptions between different namespaces

Tags: php, exception, namespaces

In the `MyApp` namespace, I have the following:

```
$class='MyApp\Callbacks\\'.$class;
$this->callback[$callBackId]=new $class();
```

This object is in the `MyApp\Callbacks` namespace and may throw a `CallbackException` (`\MyApp\Callbacks\CallbackException`) exception.

I find myself doing the following fairly often:

```
try {
    $this->callback[$callBackId]->someMethod();
}
catch(\MyApp\Callbacks\CallbackException $e) {
    throw new MyAppExeption($e->getMessage(),$e->getCode());    
}
```

How can I convert these exceptions to `MyAppException` without catching them individually.  I am thinking possible solutions are:

1. Have this object directly throw `\MyApp\MyAppExeption` exceptions instead.  This doesn't smell right.
2. Inject the `\MyApp\MyAppExeption` exception into this object.  Not sure about this either.
3. Catching `\MyApp\Callbacks\CallbackException` in a block every place I am catching `MyAppExeption`.  Don't think so.
4. Create some wrapper around it.  Sounds like this might be best, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Please advise.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this?

Comment: If you extend your individual callback exceptions from \MyApp\MyAppException, and catch \MyApp\MyAppException, then it will catch any of your individual exceptions as well

Comment: @Federkun  Which part?  Not catch them individually?  If this, just to reduce code duplication.  Do you agree that my solutions #1 and #2 are likely bad ideas?

Comment: @MarkBaker  While I happen to be the author of the callbacks classes, this may not always be the case, and was interested whether this is some more flexible approach.  If I am to extend them, why not modify all the callbacks classes and have them just directly throw ` \MyApp\MyAppException`?

Comment: Why not just catch Exception in the first place then, that way you catch everything in one simple catch.... You didn't indicate that the callbacks were all authored by different people, and therefore couldn't be changed in your environment, even though they all fall under the same MyApp namespace

Comment: An alternative is a catch for multiple different exceptions: e.g. `catch (MyException | MyOtherException $e)`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks Mark,  I didn't know I could use the multiple different exceptions format (i.e. `catch (MyException | MyOtherException $e)`).  New to PHP7?  Makes it a more viable option.  I ended up going with your earlier suggestion to extend `\MyApp\Callbacks\CallbackException` from `\MyApp\MyAppException` and it works, but requires modification of the `Callbacks` classes which isn't a deal breaker in this case, but other times would be more so.  Did my wrapping all of `Callbacks` in a wrapper make sense?  Would `__invoke` be required (those "magic" methods always scare me!).

Comment: Catching multiple exception types in a single block was introduced in PHP 7.1.0, ad is certainly very useful, particularly when you have multiple catch blocks each of which handles multiple exception types

Comment: Trying to manipulate the callbacks is probably not a good idea, it willl be an overhead to execution, and non-intuitive (and difficult to test) code; and magic methods should only ever be used sparingly, because they have a tendency to lead to voodoo code where it's not obvious what is happening and that's difficult to maintain

Comment: @MarkBaker  Glad I am not the only one afraid of dark magic!  I still want to give some thought how the following could be implemented: `$callback = new CallbackWrapper(new Callback());  //$callback now throws exception \MyApp\MyAppExeption upon inner Callbacks class throwing \What\Ever|Exception`

Answer (score 0):

I currently only need to expose a couple of methods, so I hard coded them.  If I later want more, probably will wrap in a class and use `__invoke`.

```
class MyApp
{
    private $callbacks;

    public function __construct($callbacks)
    {
        $this->callbacks=$callbacks;
    }

    public function someMethod($x,$y) {
        try {
            $this->someMethod($x,$y);
        }
        catch(\MyApp\Callbacks\CallbackException $e) {
            //Modify if desired
            throw new MyAppExeption($e->getMessage(),$e->getCode());    
        }
    }
}
```